# reaver is not working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and when I start reaver it stuck on

> WARNING: Failed to associate with AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF (ESSID: (null))

I searched and found that this problem has something to do with the newest libpcap and  I should downgrade to libpcap0.8

I did that and still didn't managed to make it work

anyone facing the same problem?

Comment: i have this problem too, i think reaver is obsulete.